# Host name and Port number for Virtual box

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, hostname, port-number

Could you please tell me how to find out the host-name and port number for Ubuntu 16.04 installed on Virtual Box?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, the port number for the virtual box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the network options of the Virtual box. Change the Network adapter attached type to Bridged Adapter(By default it is set to NAT) and run command "ifconfig" in terminal(Restart is required). IP address is displayed as a result. Generally the port number is set to 22 if you want to access ubuntu installed on Virtual box from Windows via ssh.